# cmder ssh connect in new console not run default bash

Tags: bash, ssh, cygwin, cmder

I am trying to ssh connect using cygwin bash in cmder. I set cygwin bash as default bash under *Settings>Startup>Specified named task* - I put here Cygwin bash.

When I open cmder - cygwin bash is loaded to a newly opened console. It looks fine. Even when I do 'ssh' - this bash shows me that ssh command exists. Now I want to run connect ssh in new console using ssh from cygwin.
I created a new task. Put the next commands in it:

**>ssh -J a@1.1.1.1 a@2.2.2.2 "-new_console:t:dal"**

However once I open task in new console cmder loads windows cmd in new console. Here is the mesasge cmder is saying:

```
'ssh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Current directory:
B:\cmder_mini
Command to be executed:
"C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe" /C ssh -J a@1.1.1.1 a@2.2.2.2
ConEmuC: Root process was alive less than 10 sec, ExitCode=1.
Press Enter or Esc to close console...
```

What I am doing wrong? Why cmder is still using windows cmd in new consoles?

Comment: The "I set cygwin bash as default bash" and "once task is opened in new console" are ambiguous. What **exactly** did you set and how? What have you put in the task? What Windows version are you trying at last? You got message that `ssh` executable is not found.

Comment: I am new to this site. And pitty thing that I cant add images as a new user. I have added more comments. I hope now it is clearer.